# Nested Case Statements in SQL before the main ELSE clause

Tags: sql, nested, case

I am writing a query where I would like to use a nested case statement. I can probably use the IF function or even the coalesce, but I specifically would like to the use case statement. However, writing other alternatives below for others is always welcomed. Also, if there is already a solution to this, please direct me, I have searched high and low.

My query goes like this:

`CASE WHEN priceddate is not null then 
   Case when lunchname = 'Mac' then 
        when createddate < '2/28/2019' then 'discard' 
        when createddate between '2/29/2019' and '3/10/2019' then 'Sale'
        when createddate > '3/10/2019' then 'Refrigerate' end 
   End
  Case when lunchname = 'Spaghetti' then
       when createddate .... 
       when createddate ..... end 
   End
  Case when lunchname = 'Burger' then .....end
   End
ELSE (the main else clause that goes with the main case statement
End as 'ProductLabel'`

(With each lunch item having different createddates for when they need to get discarded, when they need to sale, and when they need to refrigerate. This scenario is completely made up. I couldn't use my actual data so I produced  very VERY fictional data. Thus, if you're wondering why the data seem fake, it is).

My question comes to down to; Am I able to write a query where I have multiple nested case statements before the main ELSE clause, and if so, what is the correct way. Right now, it states that 'An Expression of non-Boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected'

Comment: You can have a reference table and use `join`.

Comment: Nesting case statements is fine.  But your statement isn't correct syntax.  Get one statement working and build up.

Comment: For the question formatting, your code should be in the place of `enter code here`, not after it.

Comment: It's difficult to understand your goal.  The keyword 'ELSE' doesn't appear in your code, and from the question I would expect to see it.

Comment: For all Commenters: Sorry about that, I was trying to look up how to write the code in Stack and was confused. I use to write questions here all the time in college and just blanked. I will edit my question now. Thanks for being patient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Case
    when priceddate is not null then  
        Case
            when lunchname = 'Mac' then 
                CASE
                    when createddate < '2/28/2019' then 'discard'  
                    when createddate between '2/29/2019' and '3/10/2019' then 'Sale'  
                    when createddate > '3/10/2019' then 'Refrigerate'
                end
            when lunchname = 'Spaghetti' then 
                CASE
                    when createddate < '2/28/2019' then 'discard'  
                    when createddate between '2/29/2019' and '3/10/2019' then 'Sale'  
                    when createddate > '3/10/2019' then 'Refrigerate'
                end
            when lunchname = 'Burger' then 
                CASE
                    when createddate < '2/28/2019' then 'discard'  
                    when createddate between '2/29/2019' and '3/10/2019' then 'Sale'  
                    when createddate > '3/10/2019' then 'Refrigerate'
                end
        end  
    else '?'
End as 'ProductLabel'
```

FYI, this is absolutely the wrong way to do this. You should have a table that contains the lunchname with columns specifying how long it is safe to refrigerate, how soon prior to expiration it needs to be put on sale, and when it needs discarded. You can then do a set based operation and not use CASE.

Comment: This data was completely made up. The data I work with deals with finances. I just started this job so I can't really create many tables as of yet. Also, we would have to back-fill A LOT of information in order to have a table for the actual data that I use, and the back-filling would have to be done by the data department which I am not a part of. However, thanks for much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of pseudo-code for CASE.  I would get the 'Spaghetti' code working first, then build from there.

```
CASE 
WHEN priceddate is not null     THEN 
    CASE 
         WHEN lunchname = 'Mac' THEN 
             GETDATE()  -- or, enter code here
         WHEN createddate < '2/28/2019' THEN  
             'discard'
         WHEN createddate BETWEEN '2/29/2019' AND '3/10/2019' THEN  
             'Sale'
         WHEN createddate > '3/10/2019' THEN 
             'Refrigerate' 
    END
ELSE

    CASE WHEN lunchname = 'Spaghetti' THEN 
         WHEN createddate ...  THEN
         WHEN createddate ...  THEN
    END
END  AS 'ProductLabel'
```

Comment: Thanks. This is actually what I was trying to avoid with having having on ONE case statement before the main ELSE clause. Example, Would if I had three lunch types: Mac and Cheese, Spaghetti, and Burger. So I want the Mac and Spaghetti to be a case statement before the Else clause. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I'm only an intermediate coder so everything is still quite challenging to write, but even more challenging to explain.

Comment: To elaborate a bit more: I would want my Mac and Spaghetti to have it's own case statement within the main case statement.